# Is it possible to make mirrored side of the mesh to appear in the uv image editor?

Tags: uv

[image]

Is it possible to make mirrored side of the mesh to appear in the uv image editor?

Comment: By default both faces will have overlapping UV coordinates. U option in Mirror modifier settings will make mirroring along U axis (aka X) but only once modifier is applied (because otherwise that geometry doesn't exist yet).